# Integral of $(f’(x))^2$

Tags: integration, derivatives

Wondering what the answer was. I am thinking maybe $\dfrac{f(x)f’(x)^3}{3}$. Do not know exactly how to solve this please help. Please put all answers even if they are only partial answers. Thank you. Note: this many or may not be possible.

Comment: Did I format your equations correctly?

Comment: Try taking a derivative of your supposed antiderivative to see if you get your original expression.

Comment: there is no closed form for $\int (f')^2$ for general $f$

Comment: For instance, symbolic integration by parts gives$$\int f'(x)^2\,\mathrm dx=f(x)f'(x)-\int f(x)f''(x)\,\mathrm dx$$or$$\int f'(x)^2\,\mathrm dx=xf'(x)^2-2\int xf'(x)f''(x)\,\mathrm dx$$Do you have a particular function $f$ in mind?